# Start nodemon with --max-old-space-size

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Previously, I was starting a nodejs sever with:

```
"start": "node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js",
```

But now it was migrated to typescript, and some change the start script to:

```
"start:ts": "nodemon server.ts",
```

But with that I'm losing the option `--max-old-space-size=1024`.

How can I start the server using `nodemon` but with `--max-old-space-size=1024` ?

I tried:

```
"start:ts": "nodemon --max-old-space-size=1024 server.ts",
```

but says:

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node --max-old-space-size=1024 server.ts` /MyProject//node_modules/arg/index.js:90
                    throw err;
                    ^

Error: Unknown or unexpected option: --max-old-space-size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered it's quite complicated to pass arguments to Node using ts-node. [As per the docs](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/configuration#node-flags), you can call Node and register ts-node in the command. You can use the `--exec` flag on nodemon to execute a custom command. Here's how I would frame the entire command:

```bash
nodemon --exec "node --max-old-space-size=1024 -r ts-node/register ./server.ts"
```

You can alternatively call ts-node directly and specify the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable:

```bash
nodemon --exec "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=1024' ts-node ./server.ts"
```